# Subwoofer does't work in Lenovo Y700

Tags: lenovo

I have a problem with subwoofer on the system operation Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have dual system Windows10 and Ubuntu. On the Windows 10 subwoofer is it work but on the Ubuntu do not work. How can I solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is bug and its related to alsa-driver. Look at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1553685

We have to wait till alsa team fix it.